# Android In-App purchase doesn't work

Tags: android, publish, in-app

I am about to publish the app to Google Play.
I tested in-app purchases with the product ID android.test.purchase and it worked fine.
Now I am trying to use the real product ID, but I always get the following UI error:

> The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.

In the log I can see following:

> D/Finsky(14007): [1] CarrierParamsAction.createCarrierBillingParameters: Carrier billing config is null. Device is not targeted for DCB 2.
>   E/Finsky(14007): [3407] FileBasedKeyValueStore.delete: Attempt to delete 'paramstHSCrkH2npg__b-wWCeLSA' failed!
>   E/Volley(14007): [3393] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/preparePurchase
>   D/Finsky(14007): [1] PurchaseFragment.handleError: Error: PurchaseError{type=2 subtype=0}

I have done all the basic setup:

- uploaded my apk to the alpha channel in developer console (to do that I had to shift my current date on PC 2 days back when releasing a signed apk), so the app status is "ready to publish" now
- added real product id and set its status to "active", used same product id in my code
- added license RSA key from console to my code
- added tester gmail account to console license settings
- installed on the device same released apk and use the tester gmail account there

What else am I missing?

Comment: i am facing the same problem do you find any solution for that??

Comment: @kunal I am also facing the same error. amilien's posted answer won't work for me...please post it if you got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to change the status "ready to publish" to "published" in the alpha channel. App will be not available in the market, but in-app purchases will work.
Then if everything is fine, app can be moved from alpha to production.

Comment: N.B. : You can't buy an In-App item with the same account of your published App.

Comment: The last time I set up IAPs it was sufficient to have the app uploaded as a draft version, but apparently "Draft Apps are no longer supported": http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps